# Is it possible to mount google drive in vifm using rclone?

Tags: vifm, rclone

I can mount my google drive using `rclone mount gdrive: localfolder`. I also know how to automatically mount a remote file system through `sshfs` within `vifm`. But is it possible to use `rclone` to mount a cloud drive within `vifm` automatically? I've tried to add the following line in `vifmrc`:

```
filetype *.drive FUSE_MOUNT2|rclone %PARAM %DESTINATION_DIR
```

and create a file named `google.drive` with the following line in it:

```
mount gdrive:
```

When I try to open the file `google.drive`, vifm displays the message of trying to mount and then hangs there forever.

To be more general, is there a generic way in vifm to handle all kinds of remote mounting programs?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and stumbled upon this unanswered question.
Here is my solution.

The command `rclone mount` by default stay runnig in the foreground while the remote is mounted, printing various messages to stdout. This is different from, say, `sshfs`, that asks the credentials in the foreground and finishes. In order for `vifm` to finish the mounting process and accept new user input, `rclone mount` somehow needs to be daemonized. It may be done via `--daemon` flag, however in this case it turns out that `vifm` jumps to the folder it have just created and displays its contents before the mounting process is finished. So, you will get what seems to be an empty folder. Pressing `CTRL-L` (maybe several times) refreshes the file listing and displays the proper contents. However, it is a bit irritating.

The other possible approach is to write a wrapper script that daemonizes `rclone mount` and waits until the mounting process is finished. The waiting may be achieved, for example, with `inotifywait` or just with `sleep`.

The wrapper script may look something like this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dest=$1; shift
nohup rclone mount $* "$dest" &> /tmp/rclone_gdrive.log &
inotifywait -me open "$(dirname "$dest")" | while read line; do
    echo "$line" | grep -q "$(basename "$dest")" && break
done
# or sleep 1
```

(I have not tested it enough, so be careful)
and in `vifmrc` you may place the following:

```
" Rclone mount
filetype *.drive
       \ {Mount google drive with rclone}
       \ FUSE_MOUNT2|<your wrapper script name> %DESTINATION_DIR %PARAM
```

Note that `%DESTINATION_DIR` goes before `%PARAMS` here (unlike the example in the question) because that's what the provided wrapper script expects.

Unfortunately, I do not know the answer for the more general part of your question.

Comment: Thank you! I guess this is a reasonable solution. What I am doing right now is to run rclone mount with --daemon flag manually once and then use vifm to access the mounted folder. The rclone daemon can also be launched by a desktop session control program. One does not need to use the fuse mount anymore in this case.